# Get notified when other computer in LAN comes on/off

Tags: windows-7, networking

What is an elegant way in Windows 7 of getting alerted whenever the other computer on your LAN starts-up and/or turns-off?
Using PING plus %ERRORLEVEL% on a loop comes to mind, but that seems too bruteforce-ish.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a "more elegant". The Windows 7 machine could generate an email or some such when it starts up. There is a startup event that Tash Scheduler can us as a trigger. Otherwise, a batch file on your machine that pings could be run from Task Scheduler every n minutes.